# Subtracting rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID       | IssueDate               
194924   | 2013-07-31 00:00:00.000 
194924   | 2010-06-15 00:00:00.000  
194924   | 2012-07-30 00:00:00.000   
194924   | 2012-12-11 00:00:00.000    
194924   | 2014-08-04 00:00:00.000    
194966   | 2012-06-02 00:00:00.000 
194966   | 2011-02-03 00:00:00.000 
194966   | 2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 
194987   | 2013-04-25 00:00:00.000 
194987   | 2010-12-03 00:00:00.000
```

I want to sort data with ID and IssueDate first, and then subtract IssueDates of two consecutive rows (to find the time between one row and next row), then calculate max, min and average of this times for each unique ID.

Comment: You could at least post the expected result.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @APH SQL server 2014

Comment: @Felix Pamittan each row, show the date of a purchase of customer with his(/her) unique ID. I want to find max, min and average time between purchase of any customers.

Comment: @Maygoon, edit your question and post the actual expected result, not a description of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Sql Server version is 2014 then the below one might be help you.

Schema for your case:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TAB (
        ID BIGINT
        ,IssuDate DATETIME
        )

    INSERT INTO #TAB
    SELECT 194924
        ,'2013-07-31 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194924
        ,'2010-06-15 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194924
        ,'2012-07-30 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194924
        ,'2012-12-11 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194924
        ,'2014-08-04 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194966
        ,'2012-06-02 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194966
        ,'2011-02-03 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194966
        ,'2011-02-01 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194987
        ,'2013-04-25 00:00:00.000'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 194987
        ,'2010-12-03 00:00:00.000'
```

Result after sorting and finding the Time difference:

```
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(DD, ISNULL(LAG(ISSUDATE)  OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,IssuDate ), IssuDate),IssuDate) AS TIME_DIFF_IN_DAYS  
    FROM #TAB
```

For aggregation with min Max & avg

```
    SELECT ID, MIN(TIME_DIFF_IN_DAYS) AS MIN_TIME_TAKEN, MAX(TIME_DIFF_IN_DAYS) MAX_TIME_TAKEN, AVG(TIME_DIFF_IN_DAYS) AVG_TIME_TAKEN FROM (
    SELECT *, DATEDIFF(DD, ISNULL(LAG(ISSUDATE)  OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,IssuDate ), IssuDate),IssuDate) AS TIME_DIFF_IN_DAYS  FROM #TAB
    )AS A
    WHERE TIME_DIFF_IN_DAYS>0  --This one you can comment if you want to show 0 diffence in time
    GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I am not asking you to insert data in #TAB. I have created it on fly for my calculations. you can directly query on your actual data. @Maygoon

Comment: Dear @Shakeer Mirza, the query works correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about "and c1.id=c.id" in CTE1 coz I am not sure about your exact requrement. Neverthless you can try some thing like,

```
declare @t table(ID int,IssuDate datetime)
insert into @t values          
(194924,'2013-07-31 00:00:00.000') 
,(194924,'2010-06-15 00:00:00.000')  
,(194924,'2012-07-30 00:00:00.000')   
,(194924,'2012-12-11 00:00:00.000')    
,(194924,'2014-08-04 00:00:00.000')    
,(194966,'2012-06-02 00:00:00.000') 
,(194966,'2011-02-03 00:00:00.000') 
,(194966,'2011-02-01 00:00:00.000') 
,(194987,'2013-04-25 00:00:00.000') 
,(194987,'2010-12-03 00:00:00.000') 

;with CTE as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id,IssuDate)rn
from @t 
)
,Cte1 as
(
select * 
,(select datediff(second,c.IssuDate,c1.IssuDate) from CTE c1 where c1.rn=c.rn+1 and c1.id=c.id)Time_between
from CTE C
)

select sum(Time_between),min(Time_between),avg(Time_between),max(Time_between) from cte1 
group by id
```